# Electroless plating

Tags: electrolysis

One of the simple methods to plate metal layers onto non-conductive surfaces is to attach graphite onto the surface. And this is what we call electroless plating.

Here, I take the electroless plating of plastics as an example.

The bonding between graphite and the plastics is predominately van der Waals’ forces. I have no ideas of how graphite and plastics can be struck together right before electroless plating, and how metal can be plated onto the surface of “graphite-plastic surface”. I was never taught that a bond can be formed between graphite and metal, or between plastic and metal.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: There is no significant bond to speak of. The structural integrity is provided by the metal shell itself, once it is thick enough.

Comment: Electroless plating is not limited to graphite usage and does not require surface conductivity. Electroless plating is chemical deposition of metals. There is requirement for metal adhesivity, but not on surface conductivity.

Comment: Do you mind providing me with more information about metal adhesivity? (Although I am more interested in the method in which graphite is used, frankly)

Comment: I have no handy resources about metal adhesivity but the famous low adhesivity of silver om nonmetalic, resp. plastic surfaces and the book "Surely you are joking, Mr. Feynman". About the graphite, I think it is not related to electroless plating, but to electrolytic plating of non-conducting surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, there is very little adhesion between graphite and *most* other surfaces -- after all, graphite can be removed from paper by rubbing with an eraser.

As mentioned in comments, a continuous metallic shell enclosing an article helps prevent peeling. Once that integrity is violated, the plated shell readily peels off.

Some alternatives provide more durable metalization:

- Evaporating metal onto glass or plastic, such as aluminum
- Etching with chromic acid-sulfuric acid, then dipping in tin(II) chloride ($\ce{SnCl2}$) and palladium chloride ($\ce{PdCl2}$) solutions to make an *adherent* conductive layer